# Form is no defined error on CakePHP observefield functionality

Tags: cakephp

I´m gettin "Form is no defined" (firebug) on this line:

```
new Form.Element.EventObserver('TareaProyectoId', function(element, value) {new Ajax.Updater('TareaHitoId','/cake/tareas/update_region_select', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request, json) {Effect.Appear('popularlist');}, parameters:Form.Element.serialize('ProyectoNombre'), requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'TareaHitoId']})})
```

In my view i hace this:

```
        echo $this->Form->input('proyecto_id',
                        array(
                            'label'=>'Nombre Proyecto:',
                            'class'=>'required',
                            'id'=>'ProyectoNombre',
                            'name'=>'ProyectoNombre',
                            'type'=>'select',
                            'style'=>'width:100px'
                        ));
    echo $this->Form->input('hito_id',
                        array(
                            'label'=>'Nombre Hito:',
                            'class'=>'required',
                            'id'=>'ProyectoNombre',
                            'name'=>'ProyectoNombre',
                            'type'=>'select',
                            'style'=>'width:100px'
                        ));
    echo $ajax->observeField('TareaProyectoId',
            array(
                'with'=>'Form.Element.serialize(\'ProyectoNombre\')',
                'url'=>'update_region_select',
                'update'=>'TareaHitoId',
                'complete'=>"Effect.Appear('popularlist');",'onChange'=>true
                )
            );
```

Can someone help me? thanks in advance.
Ah the CakePHP versión is 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok!
i forgot

```
<?php echo $javascript->link(array('prototype'));  ?>
```